# Pig ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias returned from UDF

Tags: java, hadoop, user-defined-functions, apache-pig

I am trying to load up my own UDF in pig. I have made it into a jar using eclipse's export function. I am getting this 1066 error when running my pig script. I am not sure `B = ..` as I can dump A, but I can not dump B.

### Script

```
REGISTER myudfs.jar; 
DEFINE HOUR myudfs.HOUR;

A = load 'access_log_Jul95' using PigStorage(' ') as (ip:chararray, dash1:chararray, dash2:chararray, date:chararray, getRequset:chararray, status:int, port:int);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE HOUR(ip);
DUMP B;
```

### Function

```
package myudfs;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.impl.util.WrappedIOException;

public class HOUR extends EvalFunc<String>
{
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
            return null;
        try{
            String str = (String)input.get(0);                
            return str.toUpperCase();
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw WrappedIOException.wrap("Caught exception processing input row ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

### Running command

`pig -x mapreduce 2.pig`

### Data Format

```
199.72.81.55 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0" 200 6245
   |                     |                                  |                  |    |
   ip                   date                               getRequest       status port
```

### Pig Stack Trace

```
ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias B

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias B
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:836)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:696)
at   org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:320)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:194)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:604)
at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Job terminated with anomalous status FAILED
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:828)
... 12 more
```

I am extremely unfamiliar with pig, and any and all pointers would be greatly appreciated. I know this is a lot of information to look at, but I have had no luck in mutating any data in a UDF, and I am just not sure where I went wrong.

Thanks

Comment: The error message you posted isn't helpful, would need to see the rest of the stack trace. Have you tried running the script through eclipse and debugging the udf? If you project a alias containing just ip and dump it what do you get?

Comment: @publ1c_stat1c Do you see any exceptions in corresponding Hadoop job's task logs? If so, could you post it?

Comment: @LorandBendig I get the same error when running a local job, so I think it has to do with the pig script or the udf, rather than any hadoop task. I will post the stack trace later today though, as it might help.

Comment: @AFinkelstein if I just use ip, and don't send it into my udf, everything goes as intended, and ips are print out. I have moved on from this question and redefined my error here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365207/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-certain-fields

Comment: Have you tried it in grunt shell? Does that give any more verbose errors?

Comment: FWIW, I got this error when trying to GENERATE a new relation from the output of a UDF in a FOREACH (Pig v.0.11 on Hadoop). The output of the UDF was returned as type bytearray. Casting as a chararray before the problematic FOREACH solved the problem.

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).