# ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias in certain fields, but works for others

Tags: java, alias, user-defined-functions, apache-pig

I am unable to use my udf on some fields, yet I can do it on others. If I use my first field, `ipAddress`, the udf works as intended. However, if I change it to be `date` I got the 1066 error. Here is my script.

### Pig Script that works and calls udf.

```
REGISTER myudfs.jar;
DEFINE HOUR myudfs.HOUR;

A = load 'access_log_Jul95' using PigStorage(' ') as (ip:chararray, dash1:chararray, dash2:chararray, date:chararray, date1:chararray, getRequset:chararray, location:chararray, http:chararray, code:int, port:int);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE HOUR(ip);
dump B;
```

### Pig Script that does not work, and calls udf

```
REGISTER myudfs.jar;
DEFINE HOUR myudfs.HOUR;

A = load 'access_log_Jul95' using PigStorage(' ') as (ip:chararray, dash1:chararray, dash2:chararray, date:chararray, date1:chararray, getRequset:chararray, location:chararray, http:chararray, code:int, port:int);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE HOUR(date);
dump B;
```

### Pig script that does work, but does not call udf

```
REGISTER myudfs.jar;
DEFINE HOUR myudfs.HOUR;

A = load 'access_log_Jul95' using PigStorage(' ') as (ip:chararray, dash1:chararray, dash2:chararray, date:chararray, date1:chararray, getRequset:chararray, location:chararray, http:chararray, code:int, port:int);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE date;
dump B;
```

### Sample data

```
199.72.81.55 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0" 200 6245
```

### Java UDF

```
 package myudfs;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
 import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
 import org.apache.pig.impl.util.WrappedIOException;

 public class HOUR extends EvalFunc<String>
 {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
            if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
                return " ";
         try{
             String str = (String)input.get(0);
                return str.substring(0, 1);
            }catch(Exception e){
                throw WrappedIOException.wrap("Caught exception processing input row ", e);
            }
        }
 }
```

### Error

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias B
```

If there is anything else, let me know. I get this error running locally, and over map reduce.

Comment: Is there any other output besides `ERROR 1066`?  Anything about a backend exception?  Does your script begin to execute or does it fail with this error before launching any map-reduce jobs?

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could `date` be null some of the time? In your UDF there is a null check for the tuple but no check for `input.get(0)`

If this happens, it will hit your catch block and your UDF will error out. Could possibly be causing this error...

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but isn't that what the latter half of this `if (input == null || input.size() == 0) return " ";` if statement doing?

Comment: No that's making sure there is an input, and that it has an item. Seedhead is saying that if input has an item, but it's null, AKA input.get(0) == null, than your function will error.